# Where can I find my car's ECU number? Also, is it possible to find ECU number with VIN?

Tags: honda

Its a Honda Accord Euro Luxury 2004 model

I need to change my ECU and the wrecker's is asking me for ECU number and I don't know where can I find it.

Comment: Most are stamped / printed on the ecu.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](https://qcwo.com/technicaldomain/honda-ecu-location/), you should be able to find the ECU of your Accord in the kick panel of the passenger foot well. It will be mounted vertically on the side near the A-pillar. You'd have to pull the kick panel to get to it.

Once you've found the ECU, you can find the number through this write-up:

> You located the module, but not sure if it is the engine ECM? You can make sure by checking the part number of the box. It should be in the format of “37820-Pxx-xxx” and you will find that number on its side label. The “X” in the number format can be any combination of numbers or letters. Any other number that does not start with “37820”, it is not the engine ECM, but a different module, as there are several electronic modules around the interior of the car.

> In the picture below, there is an example of a P04 engine ECM. The complete number is “37820-P04-G52”. You can notice that every time we refer to an ECM as the “P04“, “P28“, “P0A“, etc., we are referring to the three characters in the middle of the complete ECM part number, as it is the code of the ECM “family”, while the last three numbers are the country, transmission, and software version. In this same example, the “G52”, “G” indicates that is a European ECM from Great Britain of GDM (Great Britain Domestic Market), The “5” means automatic transmission (5 and greater = A/T, while “0” is M/T) and the last number, the “2” is and identifies of the version of the software (there are “0”, “1”, “2” and in some, “3”).

[image]

As far as finding the ECU according to the VIN, while you can most likely get the general model of the ECU by the VIN, it won't (in most cases) be able to tell you exactly which version of the ECU is in the vehicle. You need the original ECU to give you that information.